# Which NPM modules are preinstalled in AWS Lambda execution environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Recently I found that `aws-sdk` NPM module is preinstalled in AWS Lambda nodejs8.10. And I can't find any information in the internet about it.

Which other node.js modules are pre-installed in AWS Lambda?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html says: "Note

The Lambda service has preinstalled the AWS SDK for Node.js."  I think its safe to assume that that is the only thing pre-installed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Only the aws-sdk package is preinstalled .

All the rest is loaded from the "node_modules" directory..

You can find information about it here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html

Comment: I inadvertently loaded up a Lambda function the other day in which I forgot to include aws-sdk in my node_modules. Was quite surprised it worked and upon searching found this post. As I update various skills I am going to pull my own copy of aws-sdk from deployment. Considering the size of aws-sdk and dependencies I am glad AWS is preinstalling it. I would be curious to know when/if they update it or if it is frozen at the version that was released when you deploy.

Comment: Is the aws-sdk version listed anywhere? Or we can assume it always uses the latest?

Comment: As noted below, this answer doesn't quite tell the whole story. obviously the dependencies of `aws-sdk` are preinstalled as well, such as `lodash` (though you shouldn't rely on that)

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately the docs don't seem very specific about it, but you can grab their docker images yourself and bash in to inspect them:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:14
```

The [Dockerfile](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-base-images/blob/nodejs14.x/Dockerfile.nodejs14.x) has `ENTRYPOINT ["/lambda-entrypoint.sh"]` and by inspecting that file I was able to determine that it runs Node via `/var/runtime/bootstrap`.

`/var/runtime/bootstrap` adds various directories to `NODE_PATH` from which modules can be loaded:

```
if [ -z "$NODE_PATH" ];
then
  nodejs_mods="/opt/nodejs/node_modules"
  nodejs14_mods="/opt/nodejs/node14/node_modules"
  runtime_mods="/var/runtime/node_modules"
  task="/var/runtime:/var/task"
  export NODE_PATH="$nodejs14_mods:$nodejs_mods:$runtime_mods:$task"
fi
```

However `/opt/nodejs` doesn't exist in the image and `/var/task` is where Lambda puts your custom code.

So `/var/runtime/node_modules` is the only directory we need to inspect:

```
bash-4.2# cd /var/runtime
bash-4.2# npm ls
/var/runtime
└─┬ aws-sdk@2.1001.0
  ├── buffer@4.9.2 extraneous
  ├── events@1.1.1 extraneous
  ├── ieee754@1.1.13 extraneous
  ├── jmespath@0.15.0 extraneous
  ├── querystring@0.2.0 extraneous
  ├── sax@1.2.1 extraneous
  ├── url@0.10.3 extraneous
  ├── uuid@3.3.2 extraneous
  └── xml2js@0.4.19 extraneous
```

As you can see, only `aws-sdk` is preinstalled.  But you could use this process to determine if they add more preinstalled deps in future versions of their Node.js runtime.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find an official list so I wrote a script to create a list.

I have a number of **other libraries installed in my Lambda**, those are (excluding built-in nodejs modules which are also available of course):

```
'aws-sdk',      <-- preinstalled by AWS
'awslambda',
'base64-js',
'dynamodb-doc',
'ieee754',
'imagemagick',
'isarray',
'jmespath',
'lodash',
'sax',
'uuid',
'xml2js',
'xmlbuilder'
```

Code to generate this list:

```
function flatten(arrayOfArrays) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays)
}

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

function extPackageNames(node) {
    if (!node.children) return [];
    const arrayOfArrays = node.children.map(c => [c.name].concat(extPackageNames(c)))
    const result = flatten(arrayOfArrays)
    return result
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const rpt = require("read-package-tree")
    const module = require("module")

    const pathArg = process.env.NODE_PATH
    const allPaths = pathArg.split(":")

    // '/var/task' is this package on lambda
    const externalPaths = allPaths.filter(p => p !== "/var/task")

    // read all package data
    const ps = externalPaths.map((path) => rpt(path).catch(err => err))
    const rpts = await Promise.all(ps).catch(err => err)

    // extract the information we need
    const packagesPerPath = rpts.map(extPackageNames)
    const countPerPath = packagesPerPath.map(arr => arr.length)
    const packages = flatten(packagesPerPath)

    // remove duplicates
    const uniquePackages = packages.filter(onlyUnique)

    // remove node.js built-in modules
    const uniqueCustomPackages = uniquePackages.filter(p => !module.builtinModules.includes(p))

    const result = {
        node_path: pathArg,
        paths: externalPaths.map((e, i) => [e, countPerPath[i]]),
        uniqueCustomPackages
    }

    console.log(result)

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(result)
    };
    return response;
};
```

To run this on lambda you will need to zip it together with a `node_modules` folder containing `read-package-tree`.

Comment: Is this not useful, or missing something?

Comment: You've listed the sub-dependencies of `aws-sdk`. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/92bed994acbf1f4a0e1f362227d431354f43a5f8/package.json#L41 Relying on or require-ing those is a dangerous because those are internal to `aws-sdk` library. Also, the `imagemagick` in your list looks suspicious, it's a fairly large library. It might be coming from your Lambda Layers - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html which is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Well, that's the total list of installed modules, so of course it would contain the aws-sdk dependencies. I don't have any layers configured. I think image processing is a common use case, that's why `imagemagick` is preinstalled.

Comment: `imagemagick` was not preinstalled for me.  I created a "from scratch" Lambda function with the Node.js 12.x. runtime.  Adding `im = require('imagemagick');` caused the function to fail with `Error: Cannot find module 'imagemagick'.`

Comment: note that at the time the above list was generated it was probably still run under node 10.x. .
the list should not be taken as a guarantee to exist anyway, as it could change at any time. This answer was more about an idea for a script to find out what is installed.

Comment: Your answer specifically says: "Currently these are". But your comment says "not guarantee to exists anyway". You should either continue telling us that `imagemagick` is preinstalled, or remove this answer as fully wrong and misleading.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the "https" and the "url" package, so those at least is pre-installed. There are quite a few standard node.js modules which need a native layer.

Clearly the AWS modules are in there, for communicating with AWS services. I've used SQS, for example.

Haven't tried "fs" yet, but since it requires a native layer, and is something you might want to do (e.g. persisting stuff to /tmp) I'm assuming it's there.

Somewhere there ought to be a list. But I can't find one. Guess you just have to try, and if the **requires** fails, then you need to put a module in node_modules, then see if it demands dependencies.

Comment: Here is a list of node.js built in modules https://github.com/sindresorhus/builtin-modules/blob/master/builtin-modules.json

Comment: Thanks. That's really useful. Looks like the Lambda framework adds at least a few more, like the aws library.