# How to debug CloudFormation templates generated by Serverless orchestrated by CircleCI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, circleci, infrastructure-as-code

### Context

I feel like I need to provide a lot of context here for the full scope of the problem to be understood, so apologies in advance if this goes a bit long or ends up providing *too* much information, I just want to ward off as many follow-up questions and clarification requests as I can.

I've got a project that's a tech handoff. It used to be in production under a different owner in a different AWS account. I'm trying to re-launch it in an AWS account I control and one of the packages is creating some problems for me.

It uses Serverless to provision a couple S3 buckets and their access policies, a couple IAM roles, and a bunch of ApiGateway methods. The package relies on [nested stacks](https://github.com/aditmalik-synechron/serverless-nested-stack) to get around the 200 resource limit as described [here](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-workaround-cloudformation-200-resource-limit/#split-your-stacks-with-plugins).

Finally, the IAM user that CircleCI connects as has the `AdministratorAccess` policy attached.

### Problem

I keep getting failures from CircleCI during this step in the build

```sh
node_modules/.bin/serverless deploy --verbose --stage develop --region us-east-1 --package ./.serverless
```

The exact nature of the failure seems to be inconsistent i.e., it doesn't always fail at the same spot. At some point a resource just fails to create and the whole process rolls back. Here are a couple examples of run failures in the log with +/- 5 lines, followed by the actual error reported by Serverless

#### Run 1

```
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethod001VarOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethod002VarOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethod003VarOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethod004VarOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethod006Options
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - FuncAbcNestedStack
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - FuncDefNestedStack
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - FuncGhiNestedStack
CloudFormation - UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - org-package-develop
CloudFormation - UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - org-package-develop
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethod006Options
```

```
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  An error occurred: FuncAbcNestedStack - Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:stack/org-package-develop-FuncAbcNestedStack/RESOURCE-ID-001 was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AbcLambdaFunction]. .
```

#### Run 2

```
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethod001VarOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethod002VarOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethod005VarOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethod006Options
CloudFormation - CREATE_COMPLETE - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethod004VarOptions
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - FuncDefNestedStack
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - FuncGhiNestedStack
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - FuncAbcNestedStack
CloudFormation - UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - org-package-develop
CloudFormation - UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::CloudFormation::Stack - org-package-develop
CloudFormation - DELETE_IN_PROGRESS - AWS::ApiGateway::Method - ApiGatewayMethod001VarOptions
```

```
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  An error occurred: FuncDefNestedStack - Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:stack/org-package-develop-FuncDefNestedStack/RESOURCE-ID-002 was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [DefLambdaFunction]. .
```

> Note: All the unique identifiers in the above logs have been replaces/obfuscated by new identifiers which are unique *across* both logs, not *per* log i.e., `FuncAbcNestedStack` appears in both logs because it exact same resource in the configuration.

### Question

Given all the above, my question at this point is **how do I debug this?** This represents all the detail I (believe) is available to me in that I can't dive deeper to find out *why* a resource failed to create. I've read a bit about [troubleshooting errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html) but nothing there has been terribly helpful since I'm not actually using EC2 directly.

### Apr 4 Update

I've done a good amount of work trying to debug the templates. Mind you, I'm generally not working with the templates themselves, Serverless generates them and dumps them into an S3 bucket before they're applied.

Here are some steps I've taken

1. Updated to most recent version of Serverless (`1.67.0`, from `1.30.3`)
2. Nuked existing stacks
3. Nuked related S3 bucket
4. Updated node runtime (`12.16.1`, from `8.10.0`)
5. Downloaded and linted the CFN template that contains the failing lambda - no issues reported

I'm still getting the same results. When I re-run the build and check the CloudFormation event logs, I do see that a stack fails to create because a Lambda function within it fails to create. There's nothing special about this function (other Lambdas create successfully earlier in the run) other than the fact that it's the authorizer for every other function in the API, which may or may not be significant. I still can't find further detail as to *why* the lambda fails to create.

### Apr 6 Update

Ok, now that I understand how the CloudFormation console works, here is now what I *think* is the undermost-lying error message

```
Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 0507722d-46e7-4340-bc68-fdba1ed469d6)
```

Looking at the CFN template itself for this nested stack, I now see what is going on. Every single lamba gets its own stack, and each stack across the entire package is compiled into a single ZIP file, whose size ends up being about 270MB or 20MB larger than the limit specified above. From this point, it seems like I have two possible paths forward

1. Figure out how to split the functions across multiple ZIPs
2. Change the webpack configuration so the compiled files are less bloated (I seriously don't know what's going on here - a 1k TypeScript file is coming out as 6.5MB after webpack)

Comment: Why don't you login to the AWS console, head over to the cloud formation section --> select your stack and click on Events in the bottom pane. That should actually tell you the error you're facing

Comment: That, unfortunately, provides no additional detail that is not captured in the logs I included above.

Comment: I agree with the answer by Pat Myron here. @Peter Bailey Did you try to look into the events of the nested stack??

Comment: Is it possible to include any templates, nested stack events, or CloudWatch logs as well?

Comment: @PatMyron Yeah, I can't just now but later today/tonight. I'll post another comment when that's ready

Comment: @PatMyron Here's what I have available so for in terms of extra logging. I'm keeping it separate from the question because I don't want to include the un-obfuscated data as part of the question's history. https://gist.github.com/baileyp/f4df7058e0b8982ba6bdba7061a6db7f

Comment: That stack event is from the parent stack. The stack events for the nested stack itself will be more detailed. Even if the nested stack was recently deleted, its events can still be viewed at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home#/stacks/events?stackId=$ARN for some period of time

Comment: Yes! @PeterBailey please click on the AuthorizerFuncNestedStack in CloudFormation and paste the first failed event from there. It contains the reason why that specific nested stack failed.

Comment: @MartinLöper I think I'm missing something here. When I go to view CloudFormation > Stacks, there are only two listed (the parent-most stack for this package, and the parent-most stack for another package). Even with the "View nested" toggle switch on, that's all I see. I'm beginning to suspect that the stack splitting/nesting is not actually working. (Disclosure: Prior to this effort, I have zero experience with CFN) https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zdlwm8jrye34ew/stack-log.png?dl=0

Comment: I think the stack could be already deleted. Did you try to switch the dropdown which says "Active" on your screenshot? You should search under "Deleted" and/or "Failed". see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-view-deleted-stacks.html

Comment: @MartinLöper Yes! That's it! Thank you. I have posted an update in the original question. Now excuse me while I go research WebPack

Comment: @PeterBailey try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58884131/4122849

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to look at the nested stacks themselves. The `AbcLambdaFunction` and `DefLambdaFunction` resources should have more detailed failure stack events in the nested stacks than in the parent stacks. You'll likely need to fix `AbcLambdaFunction` and `DefLambdaFunction` in the nested stack templates, as the inconsistency is likely just due to whichever resource happened to fail first and started the rollback

If it's been a while since those templates have been run, it's likely [Lambda Runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) have been deprecated. The [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) should be able to check your templates for this and more possibilities

[AWS Lambda limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) are likely as well, I'd recommend trying [things like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58884131/4122849)

Check to see if there any CloudWatch logs as well

Comment: Thank you for this. I've made a few updates but still seem to be banging my head against the same problem. Any further insight would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention, my findings have been documented above in the original question