# While updating the lambda function of aws it's throwing the error like : Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, shell, aws-lambda

In AWS Lambda, While updating the lamba function i am gettting the error like **botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation: Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes**. Basically i am pushed the code to git repo and after that updating the lambda function through shell script to reflect the update the code into aws lambda.

But it is showing the above error. Can you please anyone help me for this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Lambda Error: Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45342990/aws-lambda-error-unzipped-size-must-be-smaller-than-262144000-bytes)

Comment: I tried that solution also. But it’s still showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

aws lambda limit the code of 250M

so, if your code is totally bigger than 250M, then you can use docker image to  release your lambda function.