# Resource handler returned message: "Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes Service: Lambda for React Application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I got this error from AWS cloudformation lambda

`Resource handler returned message: "Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes (Service: Lambda)`

for deploying React application

Should adding something like this

```
archive_system_regex_exclude:
  - (.*)node_modules(.*)
```

will solve the issue and what is the effect of this as our application is UI

What other solution could solve this ?

Thanks

Trying adding

```
archive_system_regex_exclude:
  - (.*)node_modules(.*)
```

in `lambda-transform.yml`

But I don't know how this will affect our react application

Comment: try using layers https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-layers.html maybe this can help.

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45342990/aws-lambda-error-unzipped-size-must-be-smaller-than-262144000-bytes/71920166#71920166)